# Can Elastic APM track Java Garbage Collection?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-apm

Is there a way for me to track garbage collection of my Java application using Elastic APM and the associated Java APM agent?

I'm using Spring Boot, if that makes a difference.

Out-of-the-box I'm able to see the heap and non-heap memory utilization, but I'm not sure if there is also a way to view garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

The [JVM GC metrics tracked](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/java/current/metrics.html) right now are `jvm.gc.alloc`, `jvm.gc.time`, and `jvm.gc.count`.

If you are looking for additional ones, which ones would those be? And could you [open an issue with the details](https://github.com/elastic/apm-agent-java/issues).

Comment: thank you for the response! Do you happen to know how to visualize those metrics? I'm not familiar with Kibana, but it sounds like there's some way to see them - I just haven't had success doing that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please import from saved objects option - https://github.com/elastic/apm-contrib/blob/master/apm-agent-java/dashboards/java_metrics_dashboard_7.x.json

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.